# XSLT - Mismatched tags

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement

I'm trying to use XLST with this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfDynamicData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DynamicData>
    <item>
      <name>Name</name>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:int">0</value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name>Value</name>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:long">1</value>
    </item>
  </DynamicData>  
</ArrayOfDynamicData>
```

The XLST i have at the minute is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
      xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes"
      xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors"
      exclude-result-prefixes="xs xdt err fn">
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="/">    
        <graph showNames='1' caption='##TITLE HERE##' decimalPrecision='0' >
          <xsl:for-each select="ArrayOfDynamicData/DynamicData/item">            
              <xsl:if test="name='Name'">
              <set>
                <name><xsl:value-of select='value' /></name>
             </xsl:if> 
             <xsl:if test="name='Value'">
                <value><xsl:value-of select='value' /></value>
                </set>
             </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </graph>     
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now in my head this should work, but i get an error due to the mismatched  tags. But i need data from two  blocks to be placed within one  block and i'm not sure how i can achieve this.

Thanks,
james.

Edit:

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
<set>
  <name>0</name>
  <value>2</value>
</set>
```

If i put the `<set>` tags outside the if's, I get:

```
<set>
    <name>0</name>
</set>
<set>
    <value>2</value>
</set>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This can be done in a very simple way**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <graph showNames='1' caption='##TITLE HERE##' decimalPrecision='0'>
            <set>
             <xsl:for-each select=
                "ArrayOfDynamicData/DynamicData/item[name='Name']">
                    <name>
                        <xsl:value-of select='value' />
                    </name>
                    <value>
                        <xsl:value-of select=
                         "following-sibling::item[name = 'Value'][1]/value" />
                    </value>
             </xsl:for-each>
            </set>
        </graph>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<ArrayOfDynamicData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <DynamicData>
        <item>
            <name>Name</name>
            <value xsi:type="xsd:int">0</value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>Value</name>
            <value xsi:type="xsd:long">1</value>
        </item>
    </DynamicData>
</ArrayOfDynamicData>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<graph showNames="1" caption="##TITLE HERE##" decimalPrecision="0">
   <set>
      <name>0</name>
      <value>1</value>
   </set>
</graph>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're actually treating both `item` elements independently doing it this way, which means they won't ever get combined into a single `set` element in the output. If you can guarantee that a value always follows a name, then you can do this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ArrayOfDynamicData/DynamicData/item[name='Name']">
  <set>
    <name><xsl:value-of select="value" /></name>
    <value><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::item[1]/value"></value>
  </set>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an `</xsl:if>` missing here:

```
    <xsl:if test="name='Value'">
        <value><xsl:value-of select='value' /></value>
</set>
```

*Edit*

At closer inspection, the `<set>` tag falls out of the structure. Take a good look at the entire body of `<xsl:for-each>`:

```
<xsl:if test="name='Name'">
    <set> <!-- Start tag here. -->
        <name><xsl:value-of select='value' /></name>
    <!-- no end tag -->
</xsl:if> 

 <xsl:if test="name='Value'">
    <!-- No set start tag -->
    <value><xsl:value-of select='value' /></value>
    </set> <!-- End tag here -->
 </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Hi Anders, i've updated my answer to show what i'm trying to achieve, maybe its not possible with the XML i have?

Comment: Check out @Flynn1179s answer, it takes care of that.